# Line break in vue js

Tags: vue.js

Vue js code:-

```
getTitleText(){
  let mainTitle = "";

  let getTitle = this.titleText;
  let countGetTitle = getTitle.split(" ").length;
  if(countGetTitle > 4){
      mainTitle = getTitle.replace(/(\S+\s*){1,4}/g, "$&\n");
  }
  console.log("countGetTitle = ",countGetTitle);
  console.log("getTitle = ",mainTitle);
    return mainTitle;
},
```

html:-

```
<div class="end-workout-title1">{{ getTitleText() }}</div>
```

but I am getting a full line in output. Please help me where I am getting worng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your class add the `white-space:pre` rule :

```css
.end-workout-title1{
   ...
   white-space:pre
}
```